# Forecasting on Product Families: Old Family options do not disappear

Tags: forecast

I've set up collaborative forecasting on Product Families for my Org. However, I've recently changed the options in Product Families from 'A','B','C', to 'D','E','F'. Now, instead of the Forecast changing from 'A','B','C', to 'D','E','F', it shows all 6 of the combinations. I want to get rid of 'A','B', and 'C'. How can I do this?

'A','B', and 'C' have already been deleted as options from the picklist field itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the old family options, when deleting the old option, you must select a new value to assign the old values to even if the old values do not exist.